# busybox mv with whitespaces fails silently

Tags: java, android, busybox

I'm running a device with busybox.
Folder or files with no whitespaces moved correctly, but seems that folders with whitespaces don't move correctly

```
public static boolean mv(File source, File target) {
    if (!source.exists() || !target.exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("mv -v ");
        command.append('\"');
        command.append(source.getCanonicalPath());
        command.append('\"');
        command.append(' ');
        command.append('\"');
        command.append(target.getCanonicalPath());
        command.append('\"');
        System.out.println(command.toString());
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
        return process.waitFor() == 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
mv -v "/storage/sdcard0/media/music/Progressive Death Metal" "/storage/sdcard0/Music"
```

No mv output, method just returns "false" (non-zero exit code).

And must I use canonical path, or is it okay to use absolute path and leave it to shell?

**EDIT**

I also came up that if the filename had quotes, the argument will be wrong, so I made a method adding escape characters

```
private static String getCommandLineString(String input) {
    return input.replace("\\", "\\\\")
            .replace("\"", "\\\"")
            .replace("\'", "\\\'")
            .replace("`", "\\`")
            .replace(" ", "\\ ");
}
```

And now mv looks like this

```
public static boolean mv(File source, File target) {
    if (!source.exists() || !target.exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("mv -v ");
        command.append(getCommandLineString(source.getAbsolutePath()));
        command.append(' ');
        command.append(getCommandLineString(target.getAbsolutePath()));
        System.out.println(command.toString());
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
        return process.waitFor() == 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

what I get is

```
mv -v /sdcard/media/music/Progressive\ Death\ Metal /sdcard/Music
```

But still I get silent non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Exec should ask for shell, while OutputStream should write commands.

```
private static boolean execute(boolean superuser, String command) {
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(superuser ? "su" : "sh");
        os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        os.flush();

        os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
        os.flush();

        return process.waitFor() == 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (os != null) { try { os.close(); } catch (Exception e) {} }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean mv(File source, File target) {
    if (!source.exists() || !target.exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("mv ");
        command.append(getCommandLineString(source.getAbsolutePath()));
        command.append(' ');
        command.append(getCommandLineString(target.getAbsolutePath()));
        return execute(false, command.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```